# Strange behavior when ordering in R

Tags: r, sorting

I am a little lost with the following code:

```
simula <- data.frame(
  a=sample(c("b", "a"), 10, replace=TRUE), 
  b=sample(c("bb", "aa"), 10, replace=TRUE), 
  c=rnorm(10), 
  d=rnorm(10))

order(simula$a, simula$d, decreasing=c(T,F))
```

The order statement gives an error in which it states that

> argument lengths differ

. Which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Can anyone explain me why this is giving an error?

Answer (score 0):

`stringsAsFactors = F` should solve the problem:

```
simula <- data.frame(
  a=sample(c("b", "a"), 10, replace=TRUE), 
  b=sample(c("bb", "aa"), 10, replace=TRUE), 
  c=rnorm(10), d=rnorm(10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
order(simula$a, simula$d, decreasing=c(TRUE, FALSE))
```

Otherwise the variables will be stored as factor, and sample **a / b** will only have 2 levels, compared to column **c / d** with 10 elements.

Comment: `FALSE` and `TRUE` are preferred to `F` and `T`. Note that `F <- TRUE` is perfectly legal.

Comment: Your solution works, but note that `order(simula$a, simula$d, decreasing=TRUE)` will work when a and b are factors. So, most likely the issue is something with the radix sort, which is the only method that accepts a vector of more then one arguments for decreasing.

Comment: Thanks a lots. Nevertheless, using `stringsAsFactors = F` is kind of equivalent to use `as.character` when ordering. I do know how to fix the error, what I don't really get is what is causing it.